# Questions concerning dual flush converters

Tags: plumbing

I'm considering purchasing [dual-flush converters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002NKRR7Y) for our toilets and was curious if anyone had thoughts on them. Specifically, I'd like to know:

- Are there any major disadvantages to using them?
- How difficult are they to install?
- Are there any specific considerations to keep in mind for houses using septic systems?

-M

Comment: Don't know much about converters, but I will say I love my dual-flush toilet.  It saves a lot of water compared to the old toilet I used to have, but sometimes I have to explain to people which button to push.  I'm planning on putting a 1 and 2 sticker on the buttons, as the etched I and II are not really visible (I think that might make it more self explanitory).

Comment: All new toilets in Australia have had them for 15 years or so now. There are reports of not-super-impressive results with converting very old toilets, but the concept is well proven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We put a dual flush converter on my parents toilet a year ago.  It was pretty crappy (pun intended).  The problem we found, was that the half flush didn't always clear everything out, and much of the time you had to double flush the half flush.  When we called the manufacturer, they stated that with some old toilets, the converters don't work so well.  Luckily HD was willing to take the kit back, so we returned it after a couple of weeks of trying to get it to work.

Granted, this was one of the first dual flush conversion kits, and they may be better by now, but YMMV, as it seems to depend both on the kit you get, and the toilet it is going on.

As for special considerations for septic- the less water you can use the better, so in theory converting to a dual flush should be of benefit.  After our experience with my parents, for our new house (on a septic system as well) I just went with a high efficiency 1.28GPF toilet.

Comment: Thanks Mark! You da man! That's exactly what I wanted to know. =)